# How to schedule node.js code to run at a specific time daily outside times given in scheduler?

Tags: node.js, heroku

So, I see that heroku provides the option to run a command at a specific time. Information on the scheduler here.

LINK: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler

However, if you go through the steps when setting it up, they do not provide a lot of flexibility on when you can run your code daily. For example, you can only run code at 4:00pm or 4:30pm, not 4:10pm.

How can I make it so that a node.js file would run on heroku at a specific time (like 4:10pm or 2:15pm, some time outside the options given on heroku) on a daily basis?

There appears to be no support for node.js explaining this either on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Might be just a work around, but you could start the process at the nearest time slot, that is before your desired time, let it run and wait *passively* until your desired time and let it do the actual task just then.

However notice as Heroku mentions in the documentation *Heroku Scheduler* isn't guaranteed to run the task, even though it's very reliable. If you need something critical or have something that has to been run everyday for sure, you should probably make a separate process, which handles the scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

We've added a simple Heroku add-on called [Cron To Go](https://crontogo.com/?utm_source=so&utm_medium=so&utm_campaign=answers) that does exactly that - you can use Cron expressions for accuracy and schedule one-off Dynos, just like with Heroku Scheduler.

There's also a simple Node example [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/crontogo#using-with-node-js).